# Why does Python .format() escape {} with {{}} instead of \{\}?

Tags: python

An example:

```
>>> print 'foo {}'.format('bar')
foo bar
>>> print 'foo {} {{}}'.format('bar')
foo bar {}
>>> print 'foo {} \{\}'.format('bar')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: '\\'
```

From a design standpoint, why does Python .format() escape `{}` with `{{}}` instead of `\{\}`? Since backslash is often used as the escape character, wouldn't it be more straightforward to keep it the same way?

**Edit:**

To be more specific, if I want to escape `'`:

```
>>> print 'foo {} \'\''.format('bar')
foo bar ''
```

I wonder why `{}` is specially treated here.

Comment: Doubling already escapes other format specifiers.

Comment: You would have to write `\\{`, because `\{` simply expands to `{`.

Comment: It's similar to using `%%` when using printf-style formatting.

Comment: `print 'foo {} \\{\\}'.format('bar')` does not work for me?

Comment: See the comments at the end of section [Alternative Syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/#alternate-syntax) in [PEP 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101)

Comment: @PeterWood Thank you! That makes sense. But why doesn't this problem expand to other characters such as `'`? We still use backslash to escape `'`, and `\\\'` or `\\\\\'` seems to work just fine.

Comment: @Jerry You need to escape quotes and back slashes for the python interpreter to be able to correctly parse your code. You escape `{` and `}` for the `.format` function to be able to correctly parse [format strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings). They are two different purposes.

Comment: @PeterWood I see, thank you for the explanation!